# ORDER JOIN Left not taking effect

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I must be doing something wrong as I have tried all the suggestion that came up in the search here.

I am trying to join table 1 and table 2 but from table 2 I want to select the **1 entry only** that match an id on table 1. But I don't want it to pick any entry from table 2, it needs to be the latest date.

I have

```
$query->join('LEFT', '#table_2 AS o ON a.id = o.item_id');
```

I have tried

```
$query->join('LEFT', '#table_2 AS o ON a.id = o.item_id')->order('o.date', 'DESC');
```

That re-orders all the results returned and has not effect on the join results

I also tried

```
$query->join('LEFT', '#table_2 AS o ON a.id = o.item_id ORDER BY o.date DESC');
```

This has no effect

So I am pretty stuck for quite some hours now.

EDIT:

Sorry, here it is

$db     = $this->getDbo();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

```
    $query->select(
                $this->getState(
                    'list.select',
                    'a.id AS id, a.title AS title, a.featured, a.date_created, a.users_id, a.published, '.
                                    'c.title as category_title,a.date_publish,a.date_publish_down, o.how'
                )
            );
    $query->from($db->quoteName('table_1').' AS a');
            $query->join('LEFT', 'table_2 AS o ON a.id = o.item_id')->order('o.id');
            $query->where('a.published = 1');
    $query->group($db->escape('a.id'));
    return $query;
```

Comment: Tag one RDBMS only. Is it mysql or sql-server?

Comment: I think you really need to show sample input and output here.

Comment: Yes.Post ur table1 and table2 with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will give you result in `MySQL`. It may/may not work for other RDBMS.

Specify field list you want in select statement.

```
select * from
(select a.id, field_list_you_want from table1 a
left join table2 o ON a.id = o.item_id

order by a.id,o.date desc) temp
group by id
```

Comment: I tried it like this $query->join('LEFT', '#table_2 AS o ON a.id = o.item_id ORDER BY o.date DESC'); but didn't work either

Comment: @user3750757 : I have updated the query. It should work. If it doesn't kindly specify datatype of `date` column. I have one query, `does table1 (in my sql-query) has repetitive id?`

Comment: Hi seahawk thanks for trying. I decided to order the join results by id as it will be easier than date and the latest id will always be the latest anyway. the only id I select in my sql-query is the table_1 id. I edited my initial message and added a sample of my code. It is not returning any error either, just nothing

Comment: @user3750757 : create your scenario at http://sqlfiddle.com/ and share me url once issue is generated. I will look into that.

Comment: took me a little while but I managed to create that. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/935fc4/37 as you will see there, the part inside the ( ) is where I am struggling with. ordering the results of the join before adding to the table and also limiting the number of results returned. I should have 3 rows there only, appreciate your interest

Comment: @user3750757 : Kindly verify the result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/935fc4/46 . Let me know it status so that I can update the answer.

Comment: hi seahawk, the example you sent me outputs only one row. I am actually trying to display one entry per item_id, the height obid for each item_id. so in that case it would output 3 rows instead of one. I hope it makes sense. cheers

Comment: Got it to work Instead of grouping it by user_id I grouped it by id, which did the trick. I also managed to write it in jDatabase format ( "$query->select(..." ) using subquery in the join left. thanks for your interest in helping.